# "This will merge 0 commits."

Tags: git, github, merge

I have somehow messed up my git branch badly. Certain branches didn't seem to be merged properly. I'm not sure how to explain, things just aren't how I wanted. I was working on different branches branched from `master` and then pushing them to one called `development`, but I think because I merged some of those branches together while working on them, that has somehow messed up the final result.

I went into `development` and reverted all the merges from when I started working. This should be OK since I have the original branches still. But when I try merge these branches back into `development`, the GitHub app app says there are no changes to commit. How can this be if I reverted everything?

Comment: Without knowing a lot more about how you got into your current situation I don't know if we're going to be able to answer this.

Answer (score 0):

[Reverting](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert) does not delete commits, it creates a new commit that is the inverse of the patch set. So if you're cherry picking previous commits into a new branch, the old ones won't be identified as needing to be merged.

You could attempt to rebase those same commits into a new branch, then merge those back in. The rebasing would replay and create new commits for your reverted items. Since you don't provide a lot of details, I can't give an exact answer.